# Log regression using categorical variable with lots of categories

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` that looks something like this.

```
Color   Rejection
Red     0
Orange  0
Yellow  1
Green   1
Blue    1
```

I'd like to run a log regression where "Blue" is the 0 and 1 could be Red, Orange, Yellow or Green.

My log regression set up looks like this.

```
glm(
  formula = Rejection ~ Color,
  data = df,
  family = binomial(link="logit")
)
```

How do I set things up so that "Blue" is the default while the other colors would be the "1" for the x variable in this regression analysis?

Comment: Maybe `formula = Rejection ~ I(Color!="Blue")`? Is that what you're after?

Comment: If you want to be 0 when your X is Blue in your regression model, maybe you want `relevel(df$Color, "Blue").

Answer (score 0):

So to be clear, you would like to treat Color as a categorical predictor with two levels: Blue, and non-Blue? The easiest solution would be to simply create a binary factor variable with "Blue" being the first level of the factor, and all others being grouped into the second. So something like this:

```
df$Color_Binary <- if_else(df$Color == "Blue", df$Color, "Not Blue")
df$Color_Binary <- factor(df$Color_Binary, levels = c("Blue", "Not Blue"))

mod <- glm(
  formula = Rejection ~ Color_Binary,
  data = df,
  family = binomial(link="logit")
)
```

Note that when converting to a factor variable, R creates the levels in alphabetical order by default, so the `levels` variable isn't necessary in this example, but would be if your value for "Not Blue" happened to come alphabetically before "Blue". The reason you want Blue to be the first level of you factor is because the glm function will fold the first level of each factor into the Intercept (i.e. the default) and will estimate the effects for all other levels of the factor.